# Magento 2 How to load shopping cart price rule using ID

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

How to **get condition and description of cart price rule using ID programmatically**, in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository`

```
/** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository $ruleRepository **/

$rule = $this->ruleRepository->getById($ruleId);

$rule->getDescription();
$rule->getCondition();
```

Remember to inject this class in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Using your code, I am able to get description but not working for condition .

Comment: Okay! Let's me check again.

Comment: You try to dump out the condition? You should take a look at table `salesrule`.

Comment: $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $rule=$objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load(1);
  var_dump($rule->getData()); is not working. Saying getData it not a function

Comment: We can use `Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule` to get the Model Data, however, using service contract is the best practice.

Comment: I also not able to get condition in this way, can you help me in this if there is any way to get rule condition and other details

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, How to update Rule by id ?? Any Ideas ?

Comment: $rule->getCondition(); not working

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to inject `Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository` class in your constructor to get rule data based on rule id.

After that you can use below code to retrieve various rule properties:

```
$ruleId = 25;

$ruleData = $this->ruleRepository->getById($ruleId);

// Get Rule Name
$ruleName = $ruleData->getName();

// Get Rule Description
$ruleDescription = $ruleData->getDescription();

// Get Rule From and To date
$ruleFromDate = $ruleData->getFromDate();
$ruleToDate = $ruleData->getToDate();
```

Likewise, you can retrieve all its properties. However, if you want to get rule conditions then it is little bit tricky. Suppose, if you have set rule conditions in admin as below:

[image]

Then, kindly use below code to retrieve above conditions:

```
$ruleConditions = [];
$conditionData = $ruleData->getActionCondition()->getConditions();
foreach ($conditionData as $ruleKey => $ruleAction) {                
   $ruleConditions[$ruleKey]['attribute'] = $ruleAction->getAttributeName();
   $ruleConditions[$ruleKey]['value'] = $ruleAction->getValue();
}
```

The expected output of variable **$ruleConditions** would be as below:

```
[
  0 => ['attribute' => 'category_ids',
        'value' => '487, 488, 490, 491, 492, 655, 579, 532, 543',
       ],
  1 => ['attribute' => 'quote_item_qty',
        'value' => '5',
       ],
]
```

I hope this helps to everyone looking for the same concern.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you this helped

Answer (score 0):

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

    $rule_id = 1;

    $rule=$objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($rule_id); 

    echo $rule->getIsActive(); 

    echo $rule->getDescription();
    //To get conditions
    print_r($rule->getConditionsSerialized());
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is using dependency injection. You can easily load the shipping rules using the CollectionFactory.

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory;

class SomeClass 
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $ruleCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * ProgramCode constructor.
     * @param CollectionFactory $ruleCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $ruleCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->ruleCollectionFactory = $ruleCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function somefunction() {
        $shoppingCartRules = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        <!-- more code... -->
    }
```